# TP-LINK TF-3200

Tags: 14.04, drivers

I'm new here using ubuntu and I installed 14.04 LTS. I'm trying to install a driver of TF-3200 TP-LINK and unfortunately I can't figure how to do it. I've search all over the internet and also refer to the CD of TP-LINK.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166743. You can download the drivers here: http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/?categoryid=&model=TF-3200#down

1- I extracted all the files from the zip and browsed the directory:

```
user1@host1:~/Downloads$ cd TF-3200_100628/
user1@host1:~/Downloads/TF-3200_100628$ ls
LinuxDriver       Windowns 7 64bit  Windows ME           Windows XP_2003
Novell Netware    Windows 2000      Windows Vista 32bit  Windows XP 64bit
Windowns 7 32bit  Windows 98SE      Windows Vista 64bit

user1@host1:~/Downloads/TF-3200_100628$ cd LinuxDriver/

user1@host1:~/Downloads/TF-3200_100628/LinuxDriver$ ls
compat.h  ethtool.h  mii.c  readme.txt
crc32.h   Makefile   mii.h  sundance_main.c
```

2- Loaded the kernel module drivers:

```
user1@host1:~/Downloads/TF-3200_100628/LinuxDriver$ sudo modprobe mii; sudo modprobe sundance;
```

3- Verify how if it loaded correctly; I have no card, so I'm not able to see it in dmesg. You should, though.

```
user1@host1:~/Downloads/TF-3200_100628/LinuxDriver$ dmesg | grep -i eth | tail
[    0.104998] reboot: Dell xxx xxx series board detected. Selecting PCI-method for reboots.
[    3.998768] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM95761) rev 5761100] (PCI Express) MAC address d0:67:e5:56:d0:b9
[    3.998777] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 5761 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[0])
[    3.998783] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
[    3.998788] tg3 0000:0a:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[76180000] dma_mask[64-bit]
[   39.375507] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   47.558954] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   49.294698] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   49.295255] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

Same in ip link details:

```
user1@host1:~/Downloads/TF-3200_100628/LinuxDriver$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:67:e5:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:67:20:00:00:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
j56silva@72N0BT1:~/Downloads/TF-3200_100628/LinuxDriver$
```

Comment: I already tried this one but I can't find the exact installation of the driver. it's not like in windows that you can click the driver installer or browse it. I tried all the terminal commands here but unfortunately nothing works.

Comment: I tried to run the procedure as mentioned in http://xaie.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/tp-link-tf-3200-on-debian/; Apparently no error. I edited my answer with the procedure I used. what’s the result of ifconfig and route? also, what do you have defined in /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/resolv.conf.